# Lubuntu does not have the drivers for my Intel Wireless card

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, lubuntu, iwlwifi

I have a dell inspiron 5558 and I installed Ubuntu MATE 19.10 alongside windows 10. I didn't need any driver setup for this it just worked right from the install. However, when I installed Lubuntu 19.10 the Wifi does not work. If I go to the Additional Drivers app I get [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aQxE.png) so I cannot do anything (My Wireless card is Intel Dual Band AC-3160). Why does Ubuntu MATE support the card but Lubuntu does not?

Edit: Here is the output you requested of lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; rfkill list:  
`06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless AC 3160 [8086:08b3] (rev 83)
        Subsytem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3160 [8086:8470]
        Kernel Driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
        Subsystem: Dell RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [1028:06ad]
        Kernel Driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no`

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; rfkill list`

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, sorry, I am a complete noob at linux and I just had to enable Network (AKA nm-applet) in Preferences > LXQt settings > Session settings > Autostart > enable Network, and then log out and log back in. Then it shows up as a second "no-ethernet" icon in the tray at the bottom right. It had nothing to do with the drivers at all.